# Want to have further segment from another pie chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, charts, matlab, matplotlib

I hope the picture is self-explanatory.

I have already a pie chart I have to have a further segment in the chart but it has to keep the previous parent segment intact.

[image]

I have tried this in Excel and Origin but as you know I could not find a way to have control over the relation between the parent and child pie chart.

Comment: A pie-chart is based on the full circle being 100% of the data. To add additional segments, you'll need to recalculate the entirety being the old data *plus* those items in the new data.

Comment: Yes but When I try I lose the previous segment an color.

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this goal? Do you have any code or formulas to share? And in what program or language are you attempting to do this? You seem to have tagged Microsoft Excel, Python, Matlab and Matplotlib… But each of these tools will have a different approach to doing this. So you should focus on one and — honestly — show us what you have done so far.

Comment: The picture is not self-explanatory (to me). You say ‘‘have a further segment in the chart’’, but you show five new segments.  What does ‘‘keep the previous parent segment intact’’ mean?

Comment: @Scott If you look at the chart on the right, you can see the segments all follow a color pattern of red, green and blue but with different shades of sub-segments. So I believe the original poster wants the parent shapes to retain their sizes with subdivisions in them.

Comment: @ProtimaRaniPaul,,, [Read my post, will help U to understand the mechanism behind PIE Chart](https://media-exp3.licdn.com/dms/image/C5622AQGKCPJRXSSU7w/feedshare-shrink_800/0/1615636215792?e=1626912000&v=beta&t=D2vvJFIL1-jjJ6m-FNBOS3gUDnivYZi91vtRmpgngmM) ☺

Comment: @Giacomo1968 you are absolutely correct.

Comment: You need two sources of data. For the parent chart, create a separate table using SUMIF formulas for your 3 segments. For the child chart, just use  your original data.